# logging in Mule to a non-root logger

Tags: log4j, mule

is there a way in Mule to log a message to a different logger than the default/root one?

in java, you can call a different logger, using its name from the log4j file:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("myLogger")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `logger` message processor has a `category` attribute that let's you configure the name of the logger to use.